# Monitor ongoing meetings in Microsoft Teams through Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm using the Microsoft Graph API beta to create online meetings with an application token. I use this end point to create the meetings.

```
POST /users/{userId}/onlineMeetings/createOrGet
```

Now we are looking for a way to monitor these meetings. We need to know if the meeting has started and who is in the meeting at the moment.

[Call records](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/callrecords-callrecord-get?view=graph-rest-beta) are only available after the meeting has finished.

I also tried the attendee report endpoint, but it throws an error:

```
GET /users/{userId}/onlineMeetings/{meetingId}/attendeeReport

"error": {
    "code": "InternalServerError",
    "message": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",
    "innerError": {
        "date": "2021-01-14T09:08:34",
        "request-id": "adec0849-c046-4893-9a21-c9a61703975d",
        "client-request-id": "adec0849-c046-4893-9a21-c9a61703975d"
    }
}
```

Is there any way of getting this data of an ongoing Microsoft Teams meeting. Using the Graph API, a bot or a Teams app?

Comment: I don't think its possible to get information about ongoing meeting using graph API. Let me discuss this with internal team. I will update once I get any response on this.

Comment: I agree with Manish above. Unfortunately i failed to see any such API call exists at this point. If you believe this needs to be implemented, then consider filing a Microsoft User voice.

Comment: @Erik : This isn't supported by Graph API at the moment, You can raise a user voice for this [here](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests?query=)

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, if you're prepared to create a bot. You'd need to have the bot join the call using the [Calls API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-calls?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) (this requires application permissions and Admin consent).

Once you've joined the call, you can then monitor the participants list and receive events when participants join. There is an SDK that makes this a bit easier than using raw REST Calls - more info [here](https://microsoftgraph.github.io/microsoft-graph-comms-samples/docs/)

This is slightly more complicated than just making graph calls, as you'll need to expose an HTTP endpoint to the internet so that Graph can call you with participant changes. But at this point, I think it's the only way to achieve your goal.

Comment: Thank you, we created a bot, joining Teams meetings and getting data back to a callback endpoint. So I can confirm that this works as a solution to monitor ongoing Teams meetings.

The bot we built looks good for users in our organization (profile picture, name, description, etc). But guests and users from other organisations only see a "blank" user  in the meeting. No profile picture, no name and no way to message the bot. Cannot find anything in the docs on this.

Is it possible to make the bot available to guests in the meeting?

Comment: Did you manage to get the bot to auto-join the meeting? Or is it by manual invite by a user? Working on something similar and struggling to get the bot to join the meeting

Answer (score 0):

**Re: Monitor ongoing meetings in Microsoft Teams through Graph API**

Coping the answer for better visibility.

This isn't supported by Graph API at the moment, You can raise a user voice for this [here](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests?query=).

Comment: I added a User Voice here:

https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/42484381-add-support-for-monitoring-ongoing-meetings-in-mic